# Automatic restarting of dynamically added children of a supervisor

Tags: erlang, erlang-otp

According to the Erlang/OTP manual, if I add a child to a supervisor using `supervisor:start_child` and the *supervisor* crashes, the child will not be automatically restarted.

(http://www.erlang.org/doc/design_principles/sup_princ.html#id73986)

Is there an easy workaround for this, or do I have to manually save the dynamically added children somehow and manage the restarting on my own? (My supervisor has a supervisor above, so this is possible, although not very elegant.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your supervisors are processes like any others, the difference being that they are system processes (all that `trap_exit` business). When it dies the internal state it was holding goes with it -- poof!

**THIS IS A GOOD THING**

The recovery for a supervisor dying is the same as for a worker dying (a supervisor is a worker for another supervisor, after all). What you are probably running in to is a case where the *structure* of your supervision tree isn't quite aligning with your needs. If you need jobs to persist if their supervisor dies, then those tasks are closer to the crash core of the program than you have placed them -- and that means either that they should be the children of something higher up the chain *or* (more likely) that you are overestimating their importance to the system.

The most common reason I start getting concerned about making sure a process persists is when I've given it too much responsibility. Whenever I find myself asking questions like "how can I make sure a child is restarted by a supervisor if the supervisor crashes" I stop for a few minutes and consider carefully why I am asking that question -- this *always* leads me to discovery of an architectural problem (and fixing it always incidentally make something else about the rest of the system more sensible).

**Real life example:**

In a business server there was a process module that originally was "just the client connection". It grew into managing the the network connection to the client, the translation between internal Erlang values and external protocol values, and representing the client's existence (presence, audit activity, authorization, chat, etc.) within the system. Because of audit logging I started wondering the same thing as you: if the sup dies, how can I close things the client has touched, etc. ?

Then the obviously annoying thing that had been ignored happened: simultaneous login from multiple devices became a requirement. Multi-device login is weird when there are multiples of the same "client", and so on (instead of just multiple connection processes being used by a single client process). Separating those tasks into different *processes* (not just modules) dramatically simplified things and made the state recovery structure much more obvious and clear.

**Addendum**

The OP asked "So why the difference then between static and dynamic children in this regard?" Good question. Why *do* we have static child definitions, dynamic supervision commands like [`supervisor:start_child/2`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/supervisor.html#start_child-2) and [`supervisor:delete_child/2`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/supervisor.html#delete_child-2) *and* those weird [`simple_one_for_one`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/supervisor.html#id242682) supervisors?

The key is in your use cases. Let's say I have a game server that needs to *always* have a lobby available so players can log in, chat, view the armory website, plaster the forums with noob questions and anti-developer rants, and generally waste time in other ways that are only peripherally related to the actual game. We *never* want a crash in one to bring them all down at once, but maybe we do want to be able to tell different running services to listen on the network or stop accepting connections on demand. The actual game realms, though, exist in their own separate branches of the supervision tree -- if one of them goes down we don't want it to take everything else with it, and we certainly don't want to lose the whole cluster.

So how would we structure that? All of the basic services would be written directly into the supervisor tree child definitions -- no dynamism there unless we are causing it manually. Whenever we start the system they pop up. Because we may have arbitrarily many game realms, though, while the realm definition is internally structured as a mostly statically defined supervision tree, each realm-level supervisor is a child of a simple_one_for_one supervisor that manages all realms (so if that supervisor goes down then POOF! everyone is back in the lobby, probably annoyed). The realms can be started based on our commands, a settings file or db data, or a combination of these.

It may be a good thing to delay the start of *external network services*, though. We probably have some significant startup tasks when initiating the system and listeners will probably have to be started on *different nodes* in the cluster anyway. As a way to avoid pressuring the system with network connections straight away, give us time to check the system or run tests, and have an opportunity to set the system into some specific mode (benchmarking, testing, tournament, or whatever) we may wish to delay the startup of external networking services. That is, we force the system to await a command we send it before it opens the carnival doors to the unwashed masses. We would wrap the command up in some simple call we can access from the shell or the network (like `waste_of_youth:tempt_souls(Node, Port, Cert)`), but what will happen as a result of this is a sequence of `supervisor:start_child/2` calls -- and those are dynamic.

So what happens if the network service manager dies? The connections go POOF! They won't come up again until we tell them to (not just the active connections, but the listeners -- which may have died independent of the active connections, depending on what supervisor crashed), because the system is designed that way. We could do any number of things to mitigate this, though, if it is a problem. We could have a process whose job it is to know and monitor the last state of some specific service, like external networking -- and if it changes unexpectedly initiate the call on its own. But this usually isn't what you want -- most of the time when you need services restarted automatically you want static definitions of permanent services to be read into the system at startup.

Above I mentioned different modes we may want to put the server into on startup. It is convenient to separate the child definitions from the rest of the code so that when I tell it to "start in game test mode" it loads some different spread of supervisor definitions (and will stick to that unless we mess with it). If I tell it to "start in production mode" maybe we load child definitions that include statically defined permanent networking service handlers. A set of supervisor definitions for every occasion -- and in this way you can easily create service profiles. Those dynamic supervisor commands are what let you manually shift among service states or delegate that shifting process to commands you define somewhere in your code.

Comment: So why the difference then between static and dynamic children in this regard? (Note that we are not talking about the persistence of children states, I just want them to be restarted (with clean states) with the supervisor.)

Comment: @GaborKulcsar Because sometimes you need the supervisors to be able to do things on the fly based on, say, an external instruction -- but *most* of the time you need either statically defined children (your core system services, other supervisors, listeners, etc.), or a simple_one_for_one supervisor that spawns an army of initially identical children (network connections, client resource handlers, succeed-or-crash jobs, etc.). I'll update with an example of why and where each is useful if I get some time.

Comment: @GaborKulcsar I added a discussion about that. Its not very concise, and hopefully it is not confusing. I'll probably edit it a bit one of these days for clarity. Sorry its so long -- I didn't have time to write a shorter one tonight.

Comment: Thanks - you can probably add a TL;DR section, saying - "No - this usually isn't what you want" and that would probably sum this topic up.